# Count inversion using MergSort C++

Tags: arrays, c++14, mergesort

I am trying to solve the below question, it works for all other cases except one mentioned below. Can someone please explain what is wrong with the code?

**Question** Inversion Count: For an array, inversion count indicates how far (or close) the array is from being sorted. If array is already sorted then the inversion count is 0. If an array is sorted in the reverse order then the inversion count is the maximum.
Formally, two elements a[i] and a[j] form an inversion if a[i] > a[j] and i < j.

```
int merge(long long int arr[], int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int count = 0;
    int n = mid-low+1;
    int m = high-mid;
    
    int a[n];
    int b[m];
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = arr[low+i];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        b[i] = arr[mid+1+i];
    }
    
    
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=low;
    
    while(i<n && j<m)
    {
        if(a[i]<=b[j])
        {
            arr[k]=a[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else if(b[j]<a[i])
        {
            arr[k]=b[j];
            j++;
            k++;
            count += mid-i+1;
            // cout<<"count:"<<count<<endl;
        }
    }
    
    while(i<n)
    {
       arr[k]=a[i];
       i++;
       k++; 
    }
    
    while(j<m)
    {
       arr[k]=b[j];
       j++;
       k++; 
    }
    
    
    return count;
}



int mergeSort(long long int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int count = 0;
    if(low<high)
    {
        int mid = (high+low)/2;
        
        count += mergeSort(arr, low, mid);
        count += mergeSort(arr, mid+1, high);
        count += merge(arr, low, mid, high);
    }
    return count;
}


long long int inversionCount(long long arr[], long long n)
{
    // Your Code Here      2 4 1 3 5
    
    int count = mergeSort(arr, 0, n-1);
    
    return count;
}
```

42-->no. of elements in array

468 335 1 170 225 479 359 463 465 206 146 282 328 462 492 496 443 328 437 392 105 403 154 293 383 422 217 219 396 448 227 272 39 370 413 168 300 36 395 204 312 323

desired result:
494

My Output:
1444

Comment: Did you check if your array is really sorted after the call? As you pass arr into the function,  I would expect that you can output it after the call to mergeSort to see if it is sorted at all.
Also please specify the language (e.g. as tag), this maybe will attract more users to this question.

Comment: @cyberbrain Yes, the array is sorted after the call to the function mergeSort. Also, I have added the language tag as C++. thanx for the advice

Comment: `count += mid-i+1;` doesn't look right. `i` starts counting from 0, but `mid` starts counting from `low`. Probably should be something like `n - i + 1`, give or take (reasoning about off-by-one errors is left as an exercise for the reader).